# Javascript onchange function does not work with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select, onchange

I wrote some code, which generates a form using PHP. I want to use javascript (line 57) to make more changes - by choosing something from dropdown menu (127 line):

If I select value "range", I want to generate two more inputs in the form, 
just next to the row.

[This is how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOeuY.png)

```
// Javascript
$(function() {
    $("#select1").on("change",function() {
        var value = this.value;
        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = value;
    });
});   

// HTML
<select onchange="select(this.value)" id="select1" name="type$i" size="1">
    <option value="max">Maximum the best</option>
    <option value="min">Minimum the best</option>
    <option value="range">Range</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is `(57 line)` and `(127 line)` meant to mean..?

Comment: That doesn't sound too complicated, just test `if(this.value==="range") displayTheTwoInputs()`, something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an approach if I have understood well. Hope it helps!

```js
$(function() {
          $("#select1").on("change",function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "range") {
              $("#select2, #select3").show();
            } else {
              $("#select2 , #select3").hide();   
            }
            
          });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" name="type1" size="1">
    <option value="max">Maximum the best</option>
    <option value="min">Minimum the best</option>
    <option value="range">Range</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="type2" size="1" style="display:none;">
    <option value="max">Maximum the best</option>
    <option value="min">Minimum the best</option>
    <option value="range">Range</option>
</select>
<select id="select3" name="type3" size="1" style="display:none;">
    <option value="max">Maximum the best</option>
    <option value="min">Minimum the best</option>
    <option value="range">Range</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example like this may help you. Without the full HTML we cannot offer better examples.

```js
function select(value) {
  if (value == "range") {
    $('<input>').attr({
      type: 'text',
      id: 'foo1',
      name: 'bar1'
    }).appendTo('form');
    $('<input>').attr({
      type: 'text',
      id: 'foo2',
      name: 'bar2'
    }).appendTo('form');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select onchange="select(this.value)" id="select1" name="type$i" size="1">
    <option value="max">Maximum the best</option>
    <option value="min">Minimum the best</option>
    <option value="range">Range</option>
</select>
</form>
```